# TypeError: Cannot call method 'charCodeAt' of undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack

I created a bare project with webpack with only one loader, [ts-loader](https://github.com/jbrantly/ts-loader). Webpack is failing due to the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot call method 'charCodeAt' of undefined
    at getRootLength (/home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/node_modules/typescript/bin/typescript.js:997:18)
    at Object.isRootedDiskPath (/home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/node_modules/typescript/bin/typescript.js:1051:16)
    at rootReferencePath (/home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:72:23)
    at /home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:87:93
    at Array.map (native)
    at ensureDependencies (/home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:87:35)
    at Object.loader (/home/ravioli/IdeaProjects/dummyWebpack/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:103:5)
```

When tested on vanilla Javascript files Webpack runs as expected. 
The error occurs when working with Typescript files and the ts-loader, where the origin of the error is (as you can see in the stack).

Problem solves once removing the following line:
`///<reference path="testi.d.ts" />`
(The content of the file does not affect the error - I've checked).

Here is a link to the example project, run `webpack` from the src_ts folder:
https://github.com/ravitb/dummyWebpack

What am I missing here?!

Comment: Maybe because `testi.d.ts` is empty ? What happens if you put something inside just for testing, like `interface test { }` ?

Comment: As the OP wrote, the contents of the ```d.ts``` file don't matter. We've also tested a simple interface like you have suggested.

Comment: https://github.com/jbrantly/ts-loader/issues/4? What version of ts-loader do you use?

Comment: @CodeCaster We're using 0.2.3 (A similar error occurs in 0.3.3), but the issue in the link seems to have nothing to do with the issue presented in this question. The contents of the ```d.ts``` file do not matter. They don't. It's actually empty, you can see in the link to the OP's repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue where ts-loader was pulling in TypeScript 1.5 which had breaking changes instead of sticking with TypeScript 1.4. I've pushed out a new version (0.3.4) that should take care of this. Sorry for the problem.